# WSO2 BPEL assign to mapping list or collection

Tags: wso2, variable-assignment, bpel

I am using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 and I have strange problem to assign value to mapping list.
I have message type variable ObjectMappings initialized with

```
<tns:Message xmlns:tns="http://www.test.sk">
<tns:ObjectMappings>
  <tns:ObjectMapping>
    <tns:ObjectId/>
    <tns:Id/>
  </tns:ObjectMapping>
</tns:ObjectMappings>
</tns:Message>
```

I have another collection in input variable. I iterate through input and process data. At the end I assign new Id for every processed ObjectId into variable above.

```
<bpel:copy>
  <bpel:from part="return" variable="input"><bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
    <![CDATA[Body/Object[round($Counter)]/@Id]]></bpel:query></bpel:from>
  <bpel:to part="parameters" variable="ObjectMappings"><bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
    <![CDATA[ns4:ObjectMappings/ns4:ObjectMapping[round($Counter)]/ns4:ObjectId]]></bpel:query></bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

But unfortunately it ends up with fault {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: No results for expression: 'ObjectMappings/ObjectMapping[round($Counter)]/ObjectId' against

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.test.sk">
  <tns:ObjectMappings xmlns="" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.sk">
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId/>
        <tns:Id/>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId/>
        <tns:Id/>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
  </tns:ObjectMappings>
```

Fault Data  No data available.

Fault raises at counter value = 1
When I replace index value round($Counter) with fixed value 1 it works fine. Even when I add logic to handle 2 loops with fixed values it ends up without fault.
So question is: How to assign values into collection?

Comment: I found solution in changing order when assigning new element.

Comment: Initially I added new element at the end of variable. So I had to assign value using index.
Now I add new element at the start of variable. So I can assign value by fixed index = 1  
`<bpel:to part="parameters" variable="ObjectMappings"><bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
    <![CDATA[ns4:ObjectMappings/ns4:ObjectMapping[1]/ns4:ObjectId]]></bpel:query></bpel:to>`

Comment: Another solution could be using XSL transformation to assign values. It takes 2 actions in 1: adding new element + assign values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in changing order when assigning new element.
Initially I added new element at the end of variable

`<tns:ObjectMappings xmlns="" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.sk">
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId>1</tns:ObjectId>
        <tns:Id>10</tns:Id>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId/>
        <tns:Id/>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
  </tns:ObjectMappings>`

So I had to assign value using index.
Now I add new element at the start of variable

`<tns:ObjectMappings xmlns="" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.sk">
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId/>
        <tns:Id/>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
     <tns:ObjectMapping>
        <tns:ObjectId>1</tns:ObjectId>
        <tns:Id>10</tns:Id>
     </tns:ObjectMapping>
  </tns:ObjectMappings>`

Now I can assign value by fixed index = 1

I found solution in changing order when assigning new element.
Initially I added new element at the end of variable. So I had to assign value using index.
Now I add new element at the start of variable. So I can assign value by fixed index = 1

```
<bpel:to part="parameters" variable="ObjectMappings"><bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
<![CDATA[ns4:ObjectMappings/ns4:ObjectMapping[1]/ns4:ObjectId]]></bpel:query>
</bpel:to>
```